# Add-Type load assembly from network UNC share error 0x80131515

Tags: powershell, selenium, add-type

When you want to add an assembly from a network [UNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#Uniform_Naming_Convention) share using the command:

```
$scriptPath = Split-Path ($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)
Add-Type -path "$scriptPath\selenium-dotnet\net40\WebDriver.dll"
```

you might face such an error:

```
Add-Type: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///Z:\A-Backup\Users\Administr
ator\Desktop\MAXIMO Automatic\selenium-dotnet\net40\WebDriver.dll' or one of it
s dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515
)
At Z:\A-Backup\Users\Administrator\Desktop\MAXIMO Automatic\MAXIMO Automatic.ps
1:14 char:1
+ Add-Type -path "$scriptPath\selenium-dotnet\net40\WebDriver.dll"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-Type], FileLoadException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileLoadException,Microsoft.PowerShell
   .Commands.AddTypeCommand
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The key is to allow for loading an assembly from a network path **for a PowerShell executable**. It can be done by creating the two files

C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe.config C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe.config

and paste this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: It seems you can not do this in Windows Server 2012 R2 - access denied.

Comment: Login in as a local administrator and change the ownership of the file to your account. Then assign your account modification access to the files, make the change and revert the security changes

Answer (score 4):

Re: ALIENQuake's.  I've added your fix to a PS script to install the files in the correct locations.

```
$PSPaths = 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe.config','C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe.config'
$XMLCode = @"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<configuration>
   <runtime>
         <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
"@
foreach($PSConfigFile in $PSPaths) {
    $xmlcode | Out-File -FilePath $PSConfigFile -Encoding utf8 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `Add-Type` you could:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::UnsafeLoadFrom('\\uncpath\driver.dll')
```

It'll ignore some security settings and load the library but it's, well, unsafe ;).