# Scheduled Job through PowerShell quits after 3 days

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I have a script that can legitimately run much longer than 3 days (it's a command queuing script, so it has a lot of pauses in it waiting for a job to complete). I'm using the PowerShell `Register-ScheduledJob` cmdlet to create the job.

Everything works great except, by default, the Windows Task Scheduler will stop the script if it hasn't completed after 3 days. I can work around this by going in the GUI and unchecking the '*Stop the task if it runs longer than: 3 days*' check box. I need to be able to 'uncheck' that box via Powershell code. Here's how I'm scheduling it currently:

```
$immediate = (get-date).AddMinutes(2).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm")
$scheduled_date = get-date -Format "yyyyMMMd-HHMMss"
$trigger = New-JobTrigger -Once -At $immediate
$sjo = New-ScheduledJobOption -RunElevated
Register-ScheduledJob -Name "SVC Migrations - $scheduled_date" -ScriptBlock {powershell.exe -File C:\scripts\addvdiskcopy_queue.ps1 } -Trigger $trigger -ScheduledJobOption $sjo >> C:\scripts\temp\job_scheduled.txt
```

Again, everything works great with this until 72 hours hits. Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [this thread on CodePlex](https://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/discussions/246673).

It looks like you can use the Task Scheduler Managed Library to achieve this. You'll need to download the library and load the DLL. Here is a fully working sample (just update the path to the DLL).

```
$TaskName = 'asdf';

# Unregister the Scheduled Job if it exists
Get-ScheduledJob asdf -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Unregister-ScheduledJob;

# Create the Scheduled Job
$Trigger = New-JobTrigger -At '5:00 PM' -Once;
$Option = New-ScheduledJobOption;
$Action = { Write-Host 'hi'; };
$Job = Register-ScheduledJob -Name asdf -ScriptBlock $Action -Trigger $Trigger -ScheduledJobOption $Option;

# Modify the Scheduled Job using external library
Add-Type -Path "C:\Users\Trevor\Downloads\TaskScheduler\Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler.dll";
$TaskService = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler.TaskService;
$Task = $TaskService.FindTask($TaskName, $true);
$Task.Definition.Settings.ExecutionTimeLimit = [System.TimeSpan]::Zero;
$Task.RegisterChanges();
```

I tested the library in my environment, and it works as expected. The net result is that the  "*Stop the task if it runs longer than*" checkbox is disabled.

[image: Task Scheduler]

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you very much Trevor. I did have to follow this the instructions in this link to get the DLL to be recognized: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957161/add-type-load-assembly-from-network-unc-share-error-0x80131515/19957173#19957173

Comment: @firestarter247: Cool - all you should really have to do is right-click the DLL, click "Properties" and then "unblock" the file. Can you mark off the answer as appropriate please?

Answer (score 12):

```
New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -ExecutionTimeLimit 0
```

This returns an object that can be passed to `Register-ScheduledJob`'s `-Settings` argument. For example:

```
Register-ScheduledJob `
    -Settings $(New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -ExecutionTimeLimit 0) `
    # ...further arguments...
```

Comment: please add details to your answer

Comment: Worked great for me on Windows 10 v1607 build 14393

Answer (score 8):

Just figured this out on Server 2012R2 without having to use the external DLL.
Works with Register-ScheduledTask but haven't tested with Register-ScheduledJob.

I created the with Register-ScheduledTask in a way similar to the above but without the ExecutionTimeLimit setting defined. This gave me the default of 3 days.

Then I returned the task and changed the settings as below:

```
$Task = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "MyTask"
$Task.Settings.ExecutionTimeLimit = "PT0H"
Set-ScheduledTask $Task
```

Comment: This is actually the ONLY method that worked for me! Microsoft should fix this bug.

Comment: +1 this seems to work fine for me as well. Much better than the accepted answer as there are no dependencies.

Comment: Doesnt work for me, reports `The user name or password is incorrect.`

Comment: @majkinetor when using `Set-ScheduledTask` you need to provide the user context ```$task = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName $taskName <br>
$task | Set-ScheduledTask -User "$user" -Password "$userPassword"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following settings in task definition:

```
New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -ExecutionTimeLimit "PT0S"
```

Comment: This doesn't work on server 2012 with recent powershell versions. It just throws a type error (expecting a TimeSpan). So far, I can't find a way to disable ExecutionTimeLimit. MSDN says the default value is disabled, but that's wrong, it defaults to 3 days.

Specifying "New-Timespan -Days 0", or "New-TimeSpan -Seconds 0" results in the default 3 day limit as well.

Comment: Yes, but you can use maximal timespan which is around 27 years here. That should be the same as no limit for practical purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Older post, but none of these options worked for me other than what @jdc0589 said in a comment.  I run this script on an Azure VM running Windows Server 2016 Datacenter.

```
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "java.exe" `
    -Argument "-jar `"D:\Selenium\selenium-grid-extras.jar`"" `
    -WorkingDirectory "D:\Selenium"

$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtStartup

$everyMinute = New-TimeSpan -Minutes 1
$nolimit = New-TimeSpan -Minutes 0
$settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet `
    -MultipleInstances IgnoreNew `
    -RestartInterval $everyMinute `
    -RestartCount 999 `
    -Priority 0 `
    -ExecutionTimeLimit $nolimit `
    -StartWhenAvailable `
    -DisallowHardTerminate

Register-ScheduledTask `
    -Action $action `
    -Trigger $trigger `
    -Settings $settings `
    -TaskName "Start SGE Hub" `
    -TaskPath "\Selenium Grid Extras" `
    -Description "At machine startup, run SGE so that the hub can process tests without a logon" `
    -RunLevel Highest `
    -User "SYSTEM" `
    -Force
```

[image]

Comment: It works now for me, although I am 100% sure I tried it before.