# Error when accessing DLL on specific server

Tags: powershell

I am trying to read the Version from a DLL using Powershell using this code:

```
Add-Type -Path "\\myuncpath\my.dll"
$version =  [MyProd.MyVersion]::CurrentProductVersion + '.'  + [MyProd.MyVersion]::CurrentBuild
```

It works on all of my server except one. On this one I am getting the following error:

```
Add-Type : Die Datei oder Assembly "file://\\myuncpath\my.dll" oder eine Abhängigkeit 
davon wurde nicht gefunden. Der Vorgang wird nicht unterstützt. (Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x80131515)
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
+ Add-Type -Path "\\myuncpath\my.dll"     
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-Type], FileLoadException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileLoadException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand
```

*Sorry for it being German but I guess sole the stack trace will help out as well.*

I was already comparing the config files on the different servers but there was no difference. I am not knowing of different settings on the server but I guess there has to be one.

I already tried to use `Unblock-File`, set `<loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true" />` in the config and also `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`.
However nothing worked.

**It is should be important to know, that** if I copy the file to my local machine and change the name of the file I can access it.

I hope I am missing out onto something dumb. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957161/add-type-load-assembly-from-network-unc-share-error-0x80131515/19957173#19957173

Comment: @DavidBrabant that's what I meant by set `<loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true" />` in the config