# Error occurs just in normal prompt, not ISE

Tags: powershell, assemblies, dllimport

I was confronted with the following error:

```
Add-Type : Die Datei oder Assembly "file://\\myuncpath\my.dll" oder eine Abhängigkeit 
davon wurde nicht gefunden. Der Vorgang wird nicht unterstützt. (Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x80131515)
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
+ Add-Type -Path "\\myuncpath\my.dll"     
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-Type], FileLoadException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileLoadException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand
```

*Sorry for it being German but I guess sole the stack trace will help out as well.*

And fixed it by [enabling loadFromRemoteSources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957161/add-type-load-assembly-from-network-unc-share-error-0x80131515/19957173#19957173). However this just fixes it for the Powershell ISE not for the typical command prompt that starts when I use right click -> "execute Powershell script".

Does the config not apply to the normal prompt?

**Error in English:**

```
Add-Type : Could not load file or assembly 'file://\\myuncpath\my.dl'
or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)
At line:1 char:1 + Add-Type -Path "\\myuncpath\my.dll"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-Type], FileLoadException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileLoadException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Ad‌​dTypeCommand
```

Comment: Check out [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18801440/powershell-load-dll-got-error-add-type-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-webdr), which mentions the Execution policy as well as the change you have already made. Try `Get-ExecutionPolicy` on ISE and Console; compare.

Comment: @gms0ulman Can you please suggest that as edit?

Comment: I have tried a few times but the queue is full so it is not allowed,  and the option is greyed out now. I will try again in a few minutes but thought it helpful to have in the meantime.

Comment: @gms0ulman Sadly both execution policies are `RemoteSigned` and unblocking the file did not help aswell.