# Loading WinSCP in PowerShell - Could not load file or assembly - This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime

Tags: .net, powershell, winscp, winscp-net

Error Message:

> Add-Type : Could not load file or assembly 'file:///D:\WinSCP-5.15.2-Automation\WinSCPnet.dll' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded. I placed WinSCP.dll same folder together with WinSCP.exe**

I run PowerShell v2.0.

The problem exists in the error message

The script line that causes the problem looks as following:

```
#Load WinSCP .NET assembly
Add-Type -Path "C:\users\Desktop\WinSCPnet.dll"
```

This post almost similar with this link [PowerShell runtime exception - "could not load file or assembly"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799260/powershell-runtime-exception-could-not-load-file-or-assembly) and **I tried every method posted in the link** and unable to solve it. Is there anything I missed out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have an old version of .NET Framework.

Recent versions of [WinSCP .NET assembly target .NET Framework 4.0](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library).

WinSCP 5.13.9 was the last version that worked in .NET 2.

You should use the latest version of WinSCP and .NET though. Both are security sensitive software after all.

---

*If you cannot install .NET Framework 4 (not recommended though), you can use [WinSCP scripting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting) instead of .NET assembly. WinSCP itself does not have any dependency on .NET Framework (or anything else). And [runs on all versions of Windows since Windows XP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/requirements#client).*